# Make an Origin/Destination or adjacency matrix - table in R from a data frame based on criteria -R

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

I'm having some trouble creating an "origin destination" (or adjacency) matrix in R to make a network for my data in order to visualise the data with a network plot package like "igraph".

My data looks something like the "dd" data frame:

```
dd <- data.frame(company=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                  date=c("2020_01","2020_02","2020_01","2020_02","2020_01","2020_02","2020_01","2020_02"),
                  employee1 = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","U"),
                  employee2 = c("E","NA","F","F","A","A","Z","Z"),
                  employee3 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA","B","B","Y","E"))
```

1. I want to create an adjacency matrix with company IDs (from 1 to 4 in the example), where the numbers indicate equal employees. In the example of the dd data.frame it would be all zeros except for the relation between company 1 and 3, where employee "A" is same.
2. Further, I want to create an adjacency matrix with company IDs, where the numbers indicate how many employees changed companies. In the example of the dd data.frame, it would be only 1 change between company 1 and 4 (employee "E" changed.)

I would be very glad for any suggestions since I am trying around (mainly with dplyr) but don't get anywhere near.

THANKS!!

Comment: Should companies 2 & 3 be connected because of employee B?